# HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While deploying the application in Worklight 6.3 we are encountering this error:

> "Failed to deploy application 'app_name' to MobileFirst Server: : HTTP
>   500 - Internal Server Error"

Please can you check and help. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: *HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error*: Look into Server logfiles

Comment: when we run for 1st time it works. we get this error with subsequent runs(right click on app>Run As >Run on MobileFirst Development Server) 
 Also please let me know the path from where I can check

Comment: Check what the studio's embedded server logs show.

Comment: [ERROR   ] An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest:195'
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:195)
                                                                                                                  this is the error I am getting from the server logs

Comment: Please help on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to Command Prompt > Right Click > Run as administrator.

If you are using Holoviews and jupyter notebook, then instead of using plotting dataframe on server, try plotting series values in the server. I had this same issue and changing to series helped. I dont know the exact reason for this.
Hope this helps :)